# Replace last number in version number using bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terminal

I have the following string in a file:

```
<Product Id="*" Name="NAME" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.4" Manufacturer="Manufacturer" UpgradeCode="12345">
```

I want to replace the last number field in the version value (i.e. "4") using bash command (sed?) with a new number. I want to be able to change this to any other number that I pass. I tried using:

```
sed -i -e "s#Version=\"\([0-9]\)\.\([0-9]+\)\.\([0-9]+\)\.\([0-9]+\)\"#Version=\"\1\.\2\.\3\.10\"#g" <filename>
```

but this didn't work.

Comment: While it *is* possible to update XML using `sed`, it's really not the best tool for the task unless you've got nothing else. Which is unlikely, considering you're dealing with XML to begin with.

Comment: I only need to change the version number within a bash script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give this sed line a try:

#### update

fix:

```
sed -r 's/(.*Version="[^"]*[.])[^."]+(".*)/\1foo\2/ file
```

the above line change the last `4` into `foo`. You just change the `foo` to your desired value.

Comment: This doesn't always work for large number? Appends for large numbers.

Comment: @WahajAli They didn't include the `.` so it only get the last character before the quotes. Use `sed -r 's/(.*Version="[^"]*\.)[^."]+(".*)/\1foo\2/'`

Comment: This should work also fo large number. Which one failed in your test ?

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ This is not the same, in your case you must have at least a `.` and not in Kent one but both works

Comment: @WahajAli a `[.]` was missing.. sorry, fixed in answer.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu Thats the point to have to have a `.`,that's why Kent has just updated his answer to do the same as my comment.

Comment: @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９ you are right. without the dot, the line works only for single digit. my fault.

Answer (score 1):

If you have gnu-awk, you can do yhis:

```
awk -v n=8 '{print gensub(/(Version="[0-9.]+\.)[0-9]+"/, "\\1" n "\"", "1")}' file
<Product Id="*" Name="NAME" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.8" Manufacturer="Manufacturer" UpgradeCode="12345">
```

Where `n` is the version # you want to update in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

- (cfr @９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９９) there is at least 1 dot in the version (needed to increment or modify by definition)
- it have only 1 version to change by line, and line is the good one (no preselection nor separation where XML allow several "tag" per line) and not spread on several line
- I use `[[:alnum:]]` class instead of only `[[:digit:]]` allowing letter in version like *beta*, ...

`sed 's/\([[:blank:]]Version="[^"]*[.]\)[[:alnum:]]*"/\1YourNumber"/' YourFile`

Comment: If you wanted to provide a case for both if it includes a `.` and not you could us `sed -r 's/(.*Version=")([^."]*|([^"]+\.)[^."]+)(".*)/\1\3foo\4/'`

Comment: i try to stay posix compliant, so reusable everywhere (no  `|`). Without my consraint, you are right

Comment: I thought the bar was posix compliant. It says `Alternation is supported through the usual vertical bar |.` on [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). Also the formatting in your answer is messed up somehow.

Comment: `|` is not a OR in posix version (nor escaped version). The sed posix is realy basic (less than grep BRE)